# Oracle sql error, returns error "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have made such a table and need to get the jobID from the marked data and retrieve JobDescription from another table with JobID I am new to this whole SQL environment and cannot figure out a way to get the following program correct.

[image]

```
select jobdescription,jobid from job
Where jobid =(select jobid from contract_job having max(to_date(enddate)-
to_date(startdate)) as date_diff);
```

By the way I found similar questions on the site but those didn't help me much, maybe because I have no greater understanding of the field yet.
Let me explain the scenario in case it is difficult to interpret.
I have two tables:

`JOB (JobID, JobDescription, UrgencyLevel, JobAddress, Postcode, SelectedBusinessABNNumber, IndustryID)
CONTRACT_JOB (JobID, StartDate, EndDate, CorporateClientNo)`

What I am trying to do here is that, I want to get the name of the job (JobDescription) which has the highest period of contract by subtracting EndDate and StartDate and display the JobDescription which has that same JobID.

Comment: when you try the nested query, does it work as expected?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: no I think i made some mistakes there too

Comment: the arguments you provide to the `max`function are incorrect

Comment: @NicoVanBellebut using it separately from the whole block works for eg:    `select max(to_date(enddate)-to_date(startdate)) as date_diff from contract_job `

Comment: Using the `AS` inside the `MAX` is going to cause a problem.  Also your [HAVING](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html) isn't being used as a filter at all.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I made it pretty clear using the picture after the edit, please take a look at that and help me out. I am not so good with the commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 j.jobdescription
    from job_contract jc
    inner join job j on j.jobid=jc.jobid
    order by jc.enddate-jc.startdate desc
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work.  In case of two periods of the same you can use rank instead of rownum.

```
WITH all_periods AS (
SELECT MAX(enddate - startdate) as period, jobid
  FROM contract_job
GROUP BY jobid
ORDER BY 1 DESC)
SELECT jobdescription, jobid
  FROM all_periods
  JOIN job USING (jobid)
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: I did what you said now the error says `invalid relational operator`

Comment: Oh, you need a min startdate also as currently you will return many dates.

Comment: Edited answer to include min

Comment: Apologies, recreated on my computer and have updated the correct answer for you.

Comment: You may also need to wrap enddate and startdate in to_date depending on what format they are in but the syntax is correct.